# type check failed with :tbody-tr-class for BootstrapVue b-table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to change the style of my table row after it's item was edited. I used vuex and BootstrapVue here.

*b-table* prop *tbody-tr-class* setted to *rowClass* method

```
<b-table
  :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"
  ...
>
```

rowClass method looks like

```
rowClass(item, type) {
  if (item.status) return 'table-' + item.status

}
```

Item update method in Component.vue where item status setted.

```
editItem(item) {
  item.status = 'success'
  this.$store.dispatch(UPDATE_ITEM, item)
  ...
},
```

I had an error

*Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "tbodyTrClass". Expected String, Array, got Function*

But next Description is given in official bootstrap-vue docs

> Property  tbodyTrClass
>
> Type  String, Array or **Function**
>
> Description  Classes to be applied to every row on the table. If a
>   function is given, it will be called as tbodyTrClass( item, type ) and
>   it may return an Array, Object or String.

Everything I did looks for me the same as in example [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#row-styling)

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gd87Lk6c/, are you sure you're using the most recent version of BootstrapVue?

Comment: update 2.0.0-rc.11 -> 2.0.0-rc.13 helped. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of Vue and BootstrapVue.